# Can I automate multiple isolated chrome instances with Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver

I'm using Selenium ChromeDriver in c# and am trying to launch multiple browser runs in parallel.

I can launch them in parallel alright but noted that they are running on multiple tabs in one browser.. can I somehow specify (in ChromeOptions perhaps) to run each test in a newly spawned browser?

This is my code :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestInParallel()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(scenarios, (scenario) =>
        {
            using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(devOptions))
            {
                foreach (var action in scenario.Acties)
                {
                    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(action.Url);
                    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Using multiple browser windows at the same time could give you unwanted results, for instance when using cookies, which are being shared among sessions.

Comment: yes, I would like to run them in incognito modus for that. (devOptions.AddArgument("--incognito");)

Comment: Even in incognito mode this is not possble, because sessions will also be shared in incognito modus. You can have a maximum of two concurrent sessions, one in regular mode and one in incognito mode. I seems possible with using different user profiles though, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13301965/separate-session-for-each-window

Comment: ouch....I couldn't believe it, but just spawned 4 incognito browsers and yes.... same sessionid is reused starting with the third browser..

Comment: Couldn't believe it either when I experienced it myself.

Comment: First, I think you can disable new tabs in Chrome which would then spawn a new browser instance each time you do this. Second, ideally when you test in parallel you should be using a Selenium Grid so this type of thing doesn't happen. You can either build a selenium grid yourself or use a service like SauceLabs or BrowserStack.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how you tested your sessions issue but having two webdrivers in parallel is a normal case and there should not be issues with cookies or whatever. Below is my test written in Java but you can easily implement it in C#:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:/Dev/WebDrivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriver driver2 = new ChromeDriver();
    driver1.get("https://www.amazon.com/ref=nav_logo");
    driver2.get("https://www.amazon.com/ref=nav_logo");
    System.out.println("Driver1 cookies: " + driver1.manage().getCookies());
    System.out.println("Driver2 cookies: " + driver2.manage().getCookies());
    driver1.quit();
    driver2.quit();
}
```

So here you create two instances of WebDriver and each one will be operating with its own cookies set. I just checked that with amazon website since it uses sessions to track what you're doing on the site even if you're not logged in. Below is the output:

[image]

With this approach each webdriver opens their own window (not a tab).

Comment: The behavior I saw was visually.. I'm not running headless so I just see this happening. I'll do a test and print out the cookies

Comment: You probably used the same webdriver instance. The idea is to instantiate two webdriver objects in memory. My example works for a regular chrome run. Not headless one.

Comment: I'm using a "using" statement.. scope of each webdriver instance should be isolated.

Comment: In ChromeOptions I used each time the same remote-debugging-port. Wonder if that matters

Answer (score 0):

I've asked myself an year ago the same question that you ask here.

What I came up is using [soucelab](https://github.com/saucelabs-sample-test-frameworks/Java-TestNG-Selenium/) example of using ThreadLocal for storing the webdriver objects and using Selenium-Grid to consume the webdriver requests.

I've done some load/stress test with that configuration to check how stable is selenium grid and the webdriver using that ThreadLocal approach.I've modified a little bit their samples to connect to my local selenium grid. And the result was that in testing 2 sites with 1000 iterations I get 4 failed test and 3 of them was that the site was not reachable (maybe they banned me for a certain moment of time) and 1 stale element reference which I don't know were it came from (my laptop was not in the best shape while doing that). The first failing test's was after 500-th iteration. So I can say that was pretty stable.